# How to COUNT number of rows with LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, select, count

I want to catch X rows, thus, I set `LIMIT X`; but how can I simultaneously count the total number of rows too?

Currently, I use two separate queries to do so as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM col WHERE CLAUSE
SELECT * FROM col WHERE CLAUSE LIMIT X
```

Is there a way to do this in one query?

**EDIT:** The output should be the `col` cells and the number of rows. In fact, after selecting the `col` cells, it should walk over the table to count only.

I know that it is not possible to merge these two queries, as the first return 1 row, but the second X rows. I am curious if there is a function in mysql to return the number of rows in the presence of `LIMIT`.

Comment: Could you show a line or two of your desired output?

Comment: The two queries aren't compatible, as they're currently written: One returns a single record with a single column, the other will return many columns in *X* rows. Please show an example of the desired output if you want us to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run the LIMIT, but still know how many rows would have been returned without the LIMIT.  Check out [FOUND ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: +1'ing this for `FOUND ROWS`, and while it's still executing two queries, it may be better performance than running a second COUNT(*) query (depending on queries and dataset).

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I meant. I knew that `mysql` will not leave us alone on such an important issue ;)

Comment: Glad that would help.  Don't worry, mysql will still screw you on several important issues.

Comment: @DTest: or (it may be) worse performance than running a second COUNT(*) query.

Comment: @ypercube precisely

Comment: As for performance, here's an (old) [discussion](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/) on the two options.  It feels like the results of this one experiment shouldn't necessarily condemn the whole idea.

Comment: This answer is old but the linked page says this method is "deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17 and will be removed in a future MySQL version." They now suggest using the original second query from the question.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old one but it is not valid anymore, with MySQL >= 8.0.17
cf [MySQL Function Found_Rows()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)
So we still have to issue both queries ie. add one with the `COUNT()`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in your SELECT query and then run `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS field_name,filed_name2 FROM col WHERE CLAUSE LIMIT X;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() ;
```

Comment: This would benefit from some clean up and a few more details in order for it to be more useful.